# "Invalid Index to Scalar Variable" - When Using Scikit Learn "accuracy_score"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

Not sure what is wrong exactly. However, my goal is to establish a cross-validtion python code. I know that there are various metrics, but I think that I am using the correct one. Instead of getting my desired CV10 result I am receiving an error:

"Invalid Index to Scalar Variable"

I found this on StackOverflow:
**IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable happens when you try to index a numpy scalar such as numpy.int64 or numpy.float64. It is very similar to TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_*getitem*_' when you try to index an int.**

Any help would be appreciated...

I am trying to follow :: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import cross_validation
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def main():
    #read in  data, parse into training and target sets
    dataset = genfromtxt(open('D:\\CA_DataPrediction_TrainData\\CA_DataPrediction_TrainDataGenetic.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]   
    target = np.array( [x[0] for x in dataset] )
    train = np.array( [x[1:] for x in dataset] )

    #In this case we'll use a random forest, but this could be any classifier
    cfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)

    #Simple K-Fold cross validation. 10 folds.
    cv = cross_validation.KFold(len(train), k=10, indices=False)

    #iterate through the training and test cross validation segments and
    #run the classifier on each one, aggregating the results into a list
    results = []
    for traincv, testcv in cv:
        pred = cfr.fit(train[traincv], target[traincv]).predict(train[testcv])
        results.append(accuracy_score(target[testcv], [x[1] for x in pred]) )

    #print out the mean of the cross-validated results
    print "Results: " + str( np.array(results).mean() )

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pred` variable is just a list of predictions, so you cannot index its elements (this is the reason for the error)

```
results.append(accuracy_score(target[testcv], [x[1] for x in pred]) )
```

should be

```
results.append(accuracy_score(target[testcv], pred) )
```

or if you really want a copy

```
results.append(accuracy_score(target[testcv], [x for x in pred]) )
```